# How to Opacity of field's font color in Crystal report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am trying to reduce the opacity of font color of a field, but didn't find any option from crystal report design.

Does any body know how to do that ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There is no font opacity property in Crystal Reports.

Can you explain the actual use case?  Perhaps there's an alternative approach.

Comment: We have a existing report, which contains some data, and now our customer wants us to display some data for example discounted price, in a bold, red color, with large font size.

so I am looking for a solution to add new text (I-e discounted price) in a way such that the existing report data (on which I have to add new text) should also be visible, hence I am trying to reduce the opacity of of new text field.